# Possible to get E-mail Subject for attachments in E-mail Enabled Document Library?

Tags: document-library, email, custom, folder

I can't test so sorry if I am asking here. I would like to know if for e-mail enabled document libraries, is there a field that gets populated with the E-mail subject, in particular for the attachment? I can't test cause I don't have the proper environment and I've tried searching for videos or links but I can't find anything that contains the "fields" that get populated / create automatically by SharePoint when you e-mail enable a library / list.

I don't want to do development as much as possible..

The scenario why I want to do this is that, I have specified subfolders in my Document Library that is e-mail enabled, and what I want to do is to save the attachments of an e-mail sent to it based on the Subject name of the e-mail. If the folder already exists, it just places that attachment to the currently existing subfolder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Email Enabled Libary's make subfolders for emailadresses or Subject. If the same subject is recognized it will store in the same Folder.

Answer (score 1):

In any email-enabled library you should be able to find new columns being added to the list of columns, such as Subject, Body, Sent, etc. - these are accessible as any other column, depending on your requirements.

On the other hand, that scenario you mention is available as such (choose option "save attachments in folders grouped by Subject"). For other scenarios, you would either rely on a Workflow, if you do not want coding, but maybe coding would allow you the most flexibility, requiring to implement the SPEmailEventReceiver (find an example  http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/creating-a-simple-email-receiver-for-a-document-library/)